# Convert CHAR to NUMERIC in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to set up a database that has the following columns, "number", "full names", "card no", "status". In the last column status there are many types of status, which I would like to have them converted to 0 or 1 to another column within the table, depending on the statuses. The database then, is to be pulled to another application and will use the binary column to give access to a facility.

I have not tried any code on this, still learning.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [MemberNo]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[CardNo]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [GateAccess].[dbo].[GateProxy]
```

Comment: Your question does not seem to be related to MySQL because the code in the question is for ms sql server. Corrected the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why ask a question when you havent tried anything...

First you are trying to create a table with following columns not a database.
Here is a link of how to create a table http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-table/

Second you dont really need to to convert char to numeric I would personally use CASE
here is a link on case https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/case.php

Regarding to your 'application and will use the binary column to give access to a facility' it depends on what application is pulling the data.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance above, really appreciate it. The application pulling data is a gate access application.

Answer (score 0):

This may help ...

```
DECLARE  @sampletext VARCHAR(100) = '123456';  
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT, @sampletext); -- 123456 
SELECT TRY_CAST(@sampletext AS INT); -- 123456 

SELECT TOP 1000 [MemberNo]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[CardNo]
      ,[Status]
      -- Try like this for new derived column
      ,CASE WHEN [Status] = 'yourValue'THEN 1 
            WHEN  [Status] = 'yourOtherValue' THEN 0
       END 
  FROM [GateAccess].[dbo].[GateProxy]
```

Comment: Hi Alam, added a column access. This column is the one to carry the binary values. How may I add them to populate on the column?

Comment: Can you show the expected result in tabular format.

Comment: MemberNo nvarchar(MAX) Checked
FirstName nvarchar(MAX) Checked
LastName nvarchar(MAX) Checked
CardNo         nvarchar(MAX) Checked
Status         nvarchar(MAX) Checked
Access                             bit Checked

Comment: Access column will drive from based on status, right ? value for the column Access will be  0 or 1 ?

Comment: It would be better to show the sample data and expected result.

Comment: Exactly, the access column will derive from the status. The value on Access column should be 0 (no access) 1 full access.

Comment: `-- Try like this for new derived column
      ,CASE WHEN [Status] = 'full access ' THEN 1 
            WHEN  [Status] = 'no access' THEN 0
       END`

Comment: ran & got results but its not giving an output on the access column. mainly selects the number and status

Comment: DECLARE (at)STATUS VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE (at)ACCESS INT;
SELECT TOP 1000 [MemberNo]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[CardNo]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Access]
  FROM [GateAccess].[dbo].[GateProxy]
  SELECT status 
,CASE 
WHEN [STATUS]= 'LIFE' THEN 1
WHEN [STATUS]= 'HONORARY' THEN 1 END
  FROM [GateAccess].[dbo].[GateProxy]